# Least squares for an errors-in-variables model

Tags: statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

We estimate parameter $\theta$ based on the measurements of two points $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$ for the following linear model:
$$\begin{cases} \hat{X_1} \theta = \hat{Y_1} \, ,\\ \hat{X_2} \theta = \hat{Y_2} \ , \\ X_1 = \hat{X_1}+\epsilon_1 \ , \\ X_2 = \hat{X_2}+\epsilon_2 \ , \\ Y_1 = \hat{Y_1} + f_1 \ , \\ Y_2 = \hat{Y_2} + f_2 \ .  \end{cases} $$
Where $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, f_1, f_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ are IID measurement errors and $\hat{X_1}, \hat{X_2}, \hat{Y_1}, \hat{Y_1}$ are means (true values) of the measurements.

The ordinary least squares method has the following estimation:
$$\theta_{OLS} = \frac{Y_1 X_1 + Y_2 X_2}{X_1^2 + X_2^2} \ .$$

What is the mean for $\theta_{OLS}$?

Comment: The estimation does not depend on $\sigma$ so that you can make things more easy to calculate with the standard $\sigma=1$. To observe this note that substitutions $Y_i=\sigma Y_i^*$ and $X_i=\sigma X_i^*$ result in the same expression with $Y_i$ and $X_i$ replaced by $Y_i^*$ and $X_i^*$. Secondly you could go for polar coördinates: $(X_1,X_2)=R(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ and $(Y_1,Y_2)=S(\cos\psi,\sin\psi)$. I do not guarantee anything though and am too lazy to do it myself :).